# I want to store PDF file as URL in database and also get URL of that image Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, api, file

I just want to save my image or file in the database as a URL that can easily get for the frontend. I tried it a lot but did not get a solution if anyone can get me out with this?

```
 public function addPPQuestion(Request $pp_questions)
    {
        $validate = Validator::make($pp_questions->all(), [
            'qual_cat_id' => 'required|exists:qualification_categories,qual_cat_id',
            'year_id' => 'required|exists:years,year_id',
            'course_id' => 'required|exists:courses,course_id',
            'board_id' => 'required|exists:board_of__edus,board_id',
            'paper' => 'required|mimes:pdf|max:2048',
        ]);

   

 if ($validate->fails()) {
        $messages = $validate->errors()->count() > 1 ? $validate->errors()->all() : $validate->errors()->first();
        return response()->json(['code' => 400, 'message' => $messages], 400);
    } else {
        $paper = $pp_questions->paper;
        $fileName = $paper->getClientOriginalName();
        $pp_question = pp_question_answer::create([
            'paper' => $pp_questions->paper->storeAs('', $fileName, ''),
            'qual_cat_id' => $pp_questions->input('qual_cat_id'),
            'year_id' => $pp_questions->input('year_id'),
            'course_id' => $pp_questions->input('course_id'),
            'board_id' => $pp_questions->input('board_id'),
        ]);

        return response()->json(['code' => 201, 'message' => 'Question Created Successfully',
            'object' => $pp_question], 201);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't store whole url in database because if your server name will change then it will not work in projects. So you need to store image or pdf url after public folder

Comment: you can store url custom like create url using folder name in which your are storing it and then / file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Step 1: Validate the files as you want in the api.

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

It will return JSON data as result.

```
$request->validate(['file' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg,pdf,txt,doc,docx,application/octet-stream,audio/mpeg,mpga,mp3,wav|max:204800']);
```

#### Step 2: Make a file name & store it in the folder and get the URL of it.

```
$unique_id = strtolower(str_replace('.', '', uniqid('', true)) . time());

$photoFile = $request->file('paper');

$extension       = $photoFile->getClientOriginalExtension();
$fileNameToStore = $unique_id . '.' . $extension;
$filepath        = $photoFile->storeAs('photos', $fileNameToStore);

$pp_question = Model::create([
    'paper' => $filepath,
    'qual_cat_id' => $pp_questions->input('qual_cat_id'),
    'year_id' => $pp_questions->input('year_id'),
    'course_id' => $pp_questions->input('course_id'),
    'board_id' => $pp_questions->input('board_id'),
]);

return response()->json([
    'code' => 201,
    'message' => 'Question Created Successfully',
    'object' => $pp_question
], 201);
```

#### Step 3: To display data on the front-end side.

```
$imagePath = !empty($pp_question->pdf) && Storage::exists($pp_question->pdf) ? Storage::url($pp_question->pdf) : asset(Storage::url('default/pdf.png');
```

Comment: thank you so much , just tell me that can i create new function to get my file or document?

Comment: You can modify the existing function and work on it.